# Lua Invalid Vector Field - For Loop of Mysql Rows

Tags: mysql, loops, lua, field

Really simple question as I am fairly new to LUA.

I am able to query mysql table and get two results, however I am stuck trying to loop through the table and only return a specific field 'stagecoach'

[image]

```
for key,value in pairs(HasStagecoaches) do 
   for ckey, cvalue in pairs(value) do
     print(cvalue.stagecoach)
   end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake, didn't need to loop through as far.

```
for key,value in pairs(HasStagecoaches) do 

    print(value['stagecoach'])

end
```